# Property developers buying shared freehold blocks of flats (UK)

Tags: united-kingdom, civil-law

If a block of flats is shared freehold, say 20 flats and a developer buys a load, if they buy more than a certain % can they force the sale of the remaining flats?

The block is located in England and was built in the 1970s

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "shared freehold"? Typically, one person (or company) owns the freehold, and each flat is owned separately as a leasehold. Alternatively, the flat owners may own a share of the whole property as a [commonhold](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/commonhold-property), although that is less, er, common.

Comment: Where in the united kingdom? The law for this is completely different in england and wales, and scotland

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff In Scotland it is common for each flat to be owned separately with no single building owner.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff It's certainly not commonhold as the block pre-dates when commonhold was introduced

Comment: @SpacePhoenix Properties can, in theory, be converted to commonhold, though it requires unanimous agreement from all the involved parties.